# Dropdown event not firing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, aspxgridview

I am having a DropdownLIst in the HeaderTemplate of the Grid
I have written some server side code on selectedINdexChanged  event of this dropdown
But this event never fires.
I have also Enabled the ViewState of dropdown and the Page to true
Ant ide what must be the Problem

Comment: Have you set the autopostback of the dropdown to true?

Comment: Show us the relevant code where you've created the DropDownList and where you bind it to its DataSource(or you've added the Items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem in my environment.... Please check out below code..

### This is my `gridview` in aspx page.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grvGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="grvGrid_RowDataBound">  
            <Columns>  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True"   
                    SortExpression="CustomerID" />  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName"   
                    SortExpression="CompanyName" />  
               <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <%--<asp:Label ID="lblMon1" runat="server"></asp:Label>--%>
                        <asp:DropDownList id="ddlMon" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMon_SelecdtedIndexChanges">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" Selected="True">1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblblbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>
```

### Get Grid View Bind in pageload event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetTable();
            grvGrid.DataSource = dstable;
            grvGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

### Find DropDown control and bind it's event

```
protected void grvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                DropDownList ddlmon = e.Row.FindControl("ddlMon") as DropDownList;
                ddlmon.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlMon_SelecdtedIndexChanges);
            }
        }
    }
```

### DropDown SelectedIndex Changes Event

```
protected void ddlMon_SelecdtedIndexChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your Code paste here
    }
```

Comment: Do you get your answer of not!!!! you should accept your answer, if this things is right!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem here is your `DropDownList` might not set the property

```
AutoPostBack="true" try add this to your `DropDownList`
```